# Converting date to another format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Can anybody tell me  which culture is this `'27 May 14 16:28:00 UT'` date format, and how can I convert my date to this format.

Currently I am doing like this but not getting the exact format:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("Date: Sun, 18 May 2014 0:59:56 -0400".Replace("Date: ", ""));
string NewDate = dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString().Replace("-", " ") + " UT";
```

Comment: What is your `dt` and `NewDate` exactly?

Comment: Looks like RFC 822 to me.

Comment: Your `Convert.ToDateTime` method successfully parse your `Sun, 18 May 2014 0:59:56 -0400`? What is your `CurrentCulture` by the way?

Comment: yes it successfully  parse `Sun, 18 May 2014 0:59:56 -0400`

Comment: i tried this `string NewDate = dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString("dd MMM yy HH:mm:ss") + " UT";` and it is working for me now but i am not sure it will work always

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
date.ToString("R")
```

There's a page that explains how to use `DateTime.ToString()` function to format dates as you wish.

Check it out: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check the following DateTime.ToString() options to format a DateTime value to required format.
http://www.dotnetlines.com/Blogs/tabid/85/EntryId/8/DateTime-ToString-Formats.aspx

Use them as DateTimeObject.ToString(“Format”);

In your case it will be

```
dt.ToString("d MMMM yy HH:mm:ss 'UT'");
```

Comment: You cannot hardcode `UT`, it's the Timezone used by the DateTime object, and it might vary.